# Conway's Game of Life with F# and windows forms

Tags: winforms, f#

Im trying to draw a 16x16 grid using f# and winforms. How do one go about drawing an array as squares on winforms with f# couse i really dont wanna just an grid-image.

Comment: What is "an grid-image"?

Comment: Displaying the map with an image that has a 16*16 boxes to represent the grid.
So far I have come to the conclusion that my array map[256] can be turned into a string and display 16 items per row. but since i want to place new cells with mouse click, i guess every item needs to be a button maybe?

Comment: If you make every item a separate control, they would be very slow to update. A faster way is to have a single control and render the cells in it `OnPaint`. But even that would be slow-ish if your grid becomes large enough, which is ultimately because GDI wasn't intended for real-time graphics.

Answer (score 4):

For [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), as for any task, it's best to break it down into manageable chunks:

- a mechanism to project from game coordinates to display coordinates (scaling)
- the "board" (a 2D array) with some random content
- a function to calculate the next generation
- a Windows Form to host everything and to draw upon, which also contains

  - a timer for updating the form after an interval
  - code for Deuble Buffering (avoid flicker)
  - an override for the `Paint` method to draw the automaton
  - an override for the `Click` method so that you can change cells
  - an override for the `KeyDown` method so close the form

We're using a 18 by 18 array here, since the outermost cells at the margin are considered dead. Alternatively, you might wrap around at the margins.

```
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

let xmax, ymax, scale = 18, 18, 20
let enscale x y = Point(x * scale, y * scale)
let descale (p : Point) = p.X / scale, p.Y / scale
let size = enscale xmax ymax
```

The board (mind you, an array) is mutable:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let board =
    Array2D.init xmax ymax (fun i j ->
       if rnd.NextDouble() < 0.9 then 0 else 1 )
```

We can change the board *after* we have determinded the new state, that's why the new state will be calculated as a list of tuples denoting the position and the new content of the array.

```
let nextGeneration() =
    let loop2 x y f =
        [ for x in 0..xmax - 1 do
            for y in 0..ymax - 1 do
                yield f x y ]
        |> List.iter (fun (x, y, c) -> board.[x, y] <- c)
    let chkbnds n i s =
        if n + i < 0 || n + i > s - 1 then None
        else Some(n + i)

    loop2 xmax ymax (fun x y ->
        [-1, 0; -1, -1; 0, -1; 1, -1; 1, 0; 1, 1; 0, 1; -1, 1]
        |> List.fold (fun c (i, j) ->
            match c, chkbnds x i xmax, chkbnds y j ymax with
            | Some c, Some x, Some y -> Some(c + board.[x, y])
            | _ -> None ) (Some 0)
        |> function
        | Some 3 when board.[x, y] = 0 -> 1
        | Some 2 | Some 3 when board.[x, y] = 1 -> 1
        | _ -> 0
        |> fun c -> x, y, c )
```

A Bitmap (for buffering), and the Form with overrides for `Paint`, `Click`, and `KeyDown`:

```
let bitmap = new Bitmap(size.X, size.Y)
type MyForm() as this =
    inherit Form(ClientSize = Size size)
    let timer = 
        { new Timer(Interval = 300) with
            override me.OnTick _ =
                nextGeneration()
                this.Invalidate() }

    do  this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true)
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true)
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true)
        timer.Start()

    override me.OnPaint e =
        use g = Graphics.FromImage bitmap
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.ClientSize))
        for x in 0..xmax - 1 do
            for y in 0..ymax - 1 do
                if board.[x, y] = 1 then
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 
                        Rectangle(enscale x y, Size(enscale 1 1)) )
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)

    override me.OnClick e =
        let e = e :?> MouseEventArgs
        if e.Button = MouseButtons.Right then timer.Start ()
        else
            timer.Stop()
            let x, y = descale e.Location
            board.[x, y] <- if board.[x, y] = 0 then 1 else 0
            me.Invalidate()

    override me.OnKeyDown _ =
        me.Close()
```